# add border radius to webcam video element

Tags: html, css

how can i add a border radius to a video element.
Here is my code.it works fine in mozilla-firefox ,but fails in chrome.Isnt chrome supported for video element border radius.

CSS
    #video{

```
-moz-border-radius:40px;
 webkit-border-radius:40px;
 border-radius:40px;
```

}

HTML:

```
<video id="video"  style="display:block;margin:0 auto;"></video>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `-` in `-webkit-border-radius`.

I have found this [css tricks blog](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/) to be very helpful in finding cross-browser styles.

Answer (score 0):

1. create parent div and set border radius for it
2. include video into parent div.

BTW: For modern browser you can use "border-radius" instead of "--moz-border-radius" and "-webkit-border-radius".

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
.videobox {
    width: 700px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 40px;
    }
    .video-stream {margin: 30px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="videobox">
        <video class="video-stream"  id=home_video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload=none width=640 height=264
            poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg">
          <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
          <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm'/>
          <track kind=captions src="/video-js/captions.vtt" srclang=en label=English />
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Valery for reply.But this isn't working for chrome. i am working for a webcam as a video.